# Vagrant: X Window System access possible?

Tags: virtualbox, x-windows, vagrant

Besides SSH access, is it also
possible to use Vagrant to launch a proper session running the X Window System
and a window manager such as Unity so that the graphical interface is also
available?

(I'm using the default VirtualBox with the precise32.box box, not sure why
I would want to switch to anything else such as VMware).

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out.

Once you issue the "vagrant up" command, the disk image is placed under the
"C:\Users\MyUserName\VirtualBox VMs" directory with all files required for it
to be operational, and hence shows up in the list when you launch VirtualBox.
If you shutdown the system with the "vagrant halt" you can then boot into it
directly form VirtualBox. Since logging in with username "vagrant" and password
"vagrant" will drop you into a shell and there will be no X Window System installed,
you will want to issue `sudo apt-get install xinit` and then `sudo apt-get install unity`
and `sudo apt-get install gnome`. This however won't be enough for the `startx` command
to work. What you should do instead is issue `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.
You can then issue the `startx` command to access the X Window System's graphical
user interface running Gnome and Unity. You can, of course, also configure a shell
script to be executed automatically after booting the system to install these packages
by creating a script and setting it up to run automatically by inserting its name
in the Vagrantfile.